# Understanding code in IRanges package for R what does this code mean?

Tags: r

I'm new here and all. I was just browsing through some of the questions and found this code that I dont understand and might be of use to me....They downloaded an IRanges package in R and the code has something to do with intervals.

Comment: In R, simply type `help(data.frame)` and run it to see what the help file says.

Comment: The code is a little be complicated. But it computes  the mean of column2 over intervals of column1. (col4 over intervals col3).... I think we can avoid the use of Iranges here( by a clever cut) to get the same result. thats 's said, your question is really bad. You don't give data to help us to test this fuction. I am pretty sure you pick up this code from SO. So i downvote this question because I don't see any effort from your side.

Comment: As I said in the previous comment , the code of this question , is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041684/r-programming-help-in-editing-code).

Comment: Why did you try to edit my answer ( or to remove it )?

Answer (score 0):

for more information about `tapply` see the ?tapply.

Here a version of the code using `cut` and not the package IRanges:

```
  idx <- seq(1, ncol(df), by=2)
     o1 <- lapply(idx, function(i) {  
     ## create grouping factor
     fac <- cut(df[,i],seq(0,max(df[i]),30),labels=F)
     fac[is.na(fac)] <- max(fac,na.rm=T)+1
     # compute the mean by interval
     mean=tapply(df[,i+1],fac, mean)
     # put the result in a data.frame
     fac=levels(as.factor(fac))
     d <- data.frame(mean=mean,fac=fac)
})
```

Applying this  on this [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041684/r-programming-help-in-editing-code):

```
[1]]
      mean fac
1 1.300000   1
2 1.450000   2
3 2.925000   3
4 1.700000   4
5 2.333333   5

[[2]]
      mean fac
1 2.500000   1
2 2.350000   2
3 1.516667   3

[[3]]
  mean fac
1 1.78   1
2 1.90   2
```